# Mobile Tracker using HTML 5

Tags: html

I want to develop an HTML 5 app which can track the location of a mobile phone using GPS.
How should I proceed and what API would I need.
Is it possible to develop such an app which needs not be installed on target mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the API is called the geolocation API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation is a good article about how to use it.

The key method is called watchPosition(), and works like this:

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
})
```

`do_something` will be called many times, depending on how the browser has implemented it.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/ has an example of this – check the box at the bottom.

Note that all browsers require the user to opt in to your site collecting this data.

Comment: Let me make myself more clear. I want an app where I would input the mobile number of the target phone and it will show me the location on map.

Comment: For that to work you'd need a 3rd party who would be happy to share that data – the carrier for the phone could have that data but I doubt they would share that due to privacy issues. Otherwise you'd need some application on the phone to upload their location. Picking any phone number and getting a lat and lon is clearly not going to happen.

Comment: OK suppose the target phone has the app installed and it saves the position using something like IndexedDb, then how would I make a contact with the target phone so as to fetch its location.So it is like, I am a team lead and I want to check on the location of my team members,where their phones are saving their locations.

Comment: It can't run in the background, so they would need to load this app, then it would run the code above, where do_something could for instance post the lat and lon to an external site with a database. As it can't run in the background, using an HTML app to do this would perhaps be of limited use.